# Conditional fetching fields with hibernate

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate

I have a big performance problem in my application because my entity embed two binary fields (byte[]) that i can't easily remove.

The problem is that i don't need to load those content in most cases (entity list), but only during entity edit and save.

So here is my model (simplified):

```
@Entity
public class Specimen {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "specimen")
    @Cascade( { CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)        
    protected List<Document> documents;
}

@Entity
public class Document {

    protected String name;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    protected byte[] content;
}
```

Is there a way to:

- always valuate Specimen#documents
- not valuate Document#content when I list all Specimen entities
- valuate Document#content when I load a single Specimen entity ?

Comment: Are you saying -- when a single `Specimen` is loaded, then only partial `Document` object should be loaded? ie the name attribute.

Comment: No, when a single `Specimen` is loaded, Document should be fully loaded. When multiple Specimen are loaded, in this case, document should be partial loaded. All fields except `content` (no `name` in this case).

Comment: To partially load entities `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` annotation should do exactly that. Have you provided byte code instrumentation though? Have read [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties)

Comment: Lazy loaded entities are then serialized by apache wicket. So wicket will force lazy loading. So I'm trying to find a way to set `null` to thoses fields for specific case.